# ngf-src not working with {{vm.detail.id}}

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I want to display the image preview or the user's avatar when the page is loaded but the `ngf-src` is not working as I expected:

```
<img id="avatar" class="ui centered image" ngf-src="avatar || 'http://localhost:8000/img/user_avatar/{{vm.detail.id}}.jpg'">
```

somehow I can not get the picture from the server.
It showed on the HTML like this:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8000/img/user_avatar/.jpg" id="avatar" class="ui centered image" ngf-src="avatar || 'http://localhost:8000/img/user_avatar/5.jpg'">
```

Could anyone help please!

Comment: I use ng-file-upload service so it should be ngf-src to see the preview of uploaded picture.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ngf-src="{{avatar || 'http://localhost:8000/img/user_avatar/' + vm.detail.id + '.jpg'}}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for my question, I posted it here in case if it could help someone else:

```
<img id="avatar" class="ui centered image" ngf-src="avatar || vm.avatarURL">
```

the `vm.avatarURL` is from the controller